# How can I add effect to an image after using the attr() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Situation

I have a **btn** and **image**.
I want to change the src of the image when the user click on the btn.

Then, I want to add a little effect to it like `fadeIn('slow');`

---

## I've tried

**appending** my `fadeIn('slow');` at the end of my `attr()`, but I don't any effect taking place.

```
$('#id').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#img').attr('src','/path/car.png').fadeIn('slow');  <-----HERE

});
```

---

## I've also tried

**moving** my `fadeIn('slow');` to the next line, but I don't any effect taking place either.

```
$('#id').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#img').attr('src','/path/car.png');
    $('#img').fadeIn('slow');  <-----HERE

});
```

Can someone please help me correct this ?

Comment: Is the image hidden by default? If the image is already visible it won't "re-fade" in.

Comment: It works for me: _http://jsfiddle.net/uhs2doqm/1/_

Comment: Does the image change? If not, can you provide the relevant HTML?

Comment: @jack : How can I fix it then ? there must be a way. Can you help me ?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes : I saw it. You're right . hmm...  so I can chain it. Let me investigate more.

Comment: @Ted : Yes the image change.

Comment: @rangerover.js Use .hide() before .attr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I did an example where you can change the image's src more than once:

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/stcr9a4e/)

```
$("#b1").on("click", function(){
    $("img")
        .finish().hide() // pay attention on this line -> it will end any fadeIn and then hide to do a new fadeIn
        .attr("src", "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/dog-how-to-select-your-new-best-friend-thinkstock99062463.jpg")
        .fadeIn(2000);
});

$("#b2").on("click", function(){
    $("img")
        .finish().hide() // pay attention on this line -> it will end any fadeIn and then hide to do a new fadeIn
        .attr("src", "http://blogs.psychcentral.com/life-goals/files/2014/09/cute-dog-pup.jpg")
        .fadeIn(2000);
});

$("#b3").on("click", function(){
    $("img")
        .finish().hide() // pay attention on this line -> it will end any fadeIn and then hide to do a new fadeIn
        .attr("src", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Clyde_The_Bulldog.jpg")
        .fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Is `.finish().hide()` is the key here ?

Comment: @rangerover.js Yes, they are... _.finish()_ will end any fadeIn() effect that are currently running... and _.hide()_ will prepare the img to the new fadeIn() effect.

Answer (score 1):

first use `fadeOut`, once complete use `fadeIn`

```js
$('#id').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#img').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $('#img').attr('src','http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/crountch/one-piece-jolly-roger/256/Zoro-icon.png').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="id">Click me</button><br />
<img id="img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/crountch/one-piece-jolly-roger/256/Luffys-flag-icon.png" />
```